# iOS - Display grid of icons to select

Tags: ios, forms

I'm looking to create a grid of icons from which one can be selected (see the Daytum app for an example of this).

1. Are there any existing form entry frameworks for iOS that already support this (eg QuickDialog is excellent, but doesn't support this)
2. What would be the best way to implement this? Assuming selecting an icon brings the user back to a form field with the icon populated in the field.
3. Are there any other apps apart from Daytum that use this 'model?

Answer (score 1):

Three20 has a [grid view controller](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher), that makes it pretty easy to add icons in a grid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of [AQGridView](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=AQGridView&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView&ei=SmD3TtuYDs-hOquPvbcB&usg=AFQjCNH0obVFjr3SUuNGVbwaAKFk_HTlMA). Used it in a couple of projects and i think its really really built well and easy to implement.